# Quick Sort Overflow

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, quicksort

My assignment is to benchmark the different run-times of various sorting algorithms. I was able to get all of my algorithms running. However, I run into an overflow problem when dealing with large arrays. Its possible that the recursion used for the quick sort is too deep, but I'm not sure how to simplify it. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is a sample of my constructors and quick sort:

```
 /**
 * constructor for sorting
 */
Sorting(int size) 
{
    arraySize = size;
    theArray = new int[size];
}

/**
 * creates a random array
 */
public void generateRandomArray() 
{

    for (int i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
        theArray[i] = (int)(Math.random());
    }

    itemsInArray = arraySize - 1;

}

/**
 * creates an array that is almost sorted
 */
public void almostSortedArray()
{

    for (int i=0; i <theArray.length; i++)
    {
        theArray[i] = i;
    }

    theArray[theArray.length/2] = (int)(Math.random());


    itemsInArray = arraySize -1;
}

 /**
 * quick sort
 */
public void quickSort(int left, int right) {

    int pivot = theArray[right/2];
    int pivotLocation = partitionArray(left, right, pivot);

    if (right - left <= 0)
        return;

    else {

        quickSort(left, pivotLocation - 1);
        quickSort(pivotLocation + 1, right);

    }

}

public int partitionArray(int left, int right, int pivot) {

    int leftPointer = left -1 ;
    int rightPointer = right;

    while (true) {

        while (theArray[++leftPointer] < pivot)
            ;

        while (rightPointer > 0 && theArray[--rightPointer] > pivot)
            ;

        if (leftPointer >= rightPointer) {

            break;

        } else {

            swapValues(leftPointer, rightPointer);

        }

    }

    swapValues(leftPointer, right);

    return leftPointer;

}


/**
 * Swaps higher value for 
 */
public void swapValues(int indexOne, int indexTwo) {

    int temp = theArray[indexOne];
    theArray[indexOne] = theArray[indexTwo];
    theArray[indexTwo] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Is this right? It looks like it ignores left. `int pivot = theArray[right/2];`

Comment: For errors, at least you should post also the stacktrace and point out which line is with the problem. Also it is always good to provide a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Answer (score 0):

Use long or BigInteger instead of int. Overflow means that the number is bigger than int can hold.

Answer (score 0):

Is it arrayIndexOutOfBound or overflow? Look at the code where you increment the leftpointer in while loop. Suppose all elements are less than pivot then you are trying to acces an element which does not exist and you should get ArrayIndexOutOfBound. Same goes for right pointer, you need to put break in while loop on the condition that if pointer reaches right end then loop should terminante.

```
`public int partitionArray(int left, int right, int pivot) {
int leftPointer = left -1 ;
int rightPointer = right;

while (true) {

    while (theArray[++leftPointer] < pivot){
        if(leftPointer == rightPointer) break; // Here i think you got IndexOutOfBound
}
    while (rightPointer > 0 && theArray[--rightPointer] > pivot)
        if(rightPointer == LeftPointer) break;

    if (leftPointer >= rightPointer) {

        break;

    } else {

        swapValues(leftPointer, rightPointer);

    }

}

swapValues(leftPointer, right);`
```

Comment: @John yes then it's problem with your recursion because you keep getting wrong values for pivot also btw try and check the debugger, once you implement the quicksort correctly , it will not give this exception as it is one of the best algorithms

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tired it but it still throws me the same error. It reads

"java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at Sorting.quickSort(Sorting.java:158)
 at Sorting.quickSort(Sorting.java:165)
 at Sorting.quickSort(Sorting.java:165)"

That also happens to be the lines:
int pivotLocation = partitionArray(left, right, pivot); 
quickSort(left, pivotLocation - 1);

I'm still pretty new at this so forgive my ignorance, any other suggestions? I appreciate the help

Comment: post your full i try to see